# Why don't we learn the variance/covariance of clusters in k-means in every iteration?

Tags: clustering

In Gaussian mixture models, every iteration computes the mean and covariance matrix for each cluster using soft assignment.
$$\mu_k = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n p(c_i=k|x_i)x_i}{\sum_{i=1}^np(c_i=k|x_i)}$$
$$\Sigma_k = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n p(c_i=k|x_i)(x_i-\mu_k)(x_i-\mu_k)^\mathrm{T}}{\sum_{i=1}^np(c_i=k|x_i)}$$

In contrast, it is common in k-means to only compute the mean of each cluster using hard assignment, but not the covariance. Is there any specific reason for that? If I compute the covariance of each cluster using hard-assignment per iteration, will I run into trouble?

**Updates**: Why is this question getting downvoted?

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: It sounds like you're asking about estimating covariance matrices on each iteration and using them (along with the centroids) to make hard cluster assignments. This is k-means using the Mahalanobis distance metric. There are various papers in the literature describing this, e.g. Melnykov and Melnykov (2014) On k-means algorithm with the use of Mahalanobis distances. The benefit is being able to find non-spherical clusters. The cost is increased computation, making sure you get good covariance estimates, and trickier initialization.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was helpful. If you could put this as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pay the cost of computing the covariance, why use something like k-means then?

You are 90% of GMM, then you may just dotted entire GMM and not something half-baked. GMM has good theoretical support, k-means - in its simplicity - also has theoretical support, but the half-k-means-half-GMM has nothing. No solid theoretical foundation, and no runtime benefits or anything over real GMM.